# Convert a universal application to iPhone-only

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

How can I convert a universal application I have made to an iPhone-only application in Xcode?

Comment: Isn't there a little dropdown in the project settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Universal project to iPhone only project xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020813/universal-project-to-iphone-only-project-xcode)

Comment: @DanF While that is a duplicate (in fact its a duplicate posted by the same user) this one has an answer and that one has already been closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set *Targeted Device Family* in the *Deployment* section of the build settings.

To clarify, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer for my stupid question! It worked :)

Comment: That wont be sufficient, you have to remove the story board files, xibs etc associated with iPad version.